# How could this be possible? UITableView datasource Count Weird Behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I don't understand how this is possible or why this is happening. Can anyone give me an idea?

I added more code to help you figure it out, however, i'm not sure how the extra code will help.

```
NSMutableArray *messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"message"];

[query whereKey:@"receiver" equalTo:currentUser.objectId];

[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (!error && objects !=NULL) {
        NSMutableArray *listOfLastMsgs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            Boolean *tester = false;
            for(int i = 0;i<listOfLastMsgs.count;i++){


                if([[object objectForKey:@"sender"] isEqualToString:[[listOfLastMsgs objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sender"]]){
                    tester = true;
                }
            }
            if(!tester){
                [listOfLastMsgs addObject:object];
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0;i<listOfLastMsgs.count;i++){
            NSString *s = [[listOfLastMsgs objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"message"];

            if(s.length > 80){
                s = [s substringToIndex:80];
            }
            [messages addObject:s];

        }

        NSLog(@"in did load %lu", (unsigned long)messages.count);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.

NSLog(@"in number of rows %lu", (unsigned long)messages.count);
return messages.count;
}
```

Here is my output log

```
2014-07-25 18:15:32.980 myapp[5696:60b] in number of rows 0
2014-07-25 18:15:35.990 myapp[5696:60b] in did load 2
2014-07-25 18:15:35.991 myapp[5696:60b] in number of rows 0
```

Comment: What is `messages`? How is it declared?

Comment: To see a bit more of the class would be useful. We don't know what else is dealing with your array of messages which could affect this. Where is the array initialised for example?

Comment: Is that the actual real, complete code for both methods?

Comment: in viewDidLoad... like this .... NSMutableArray *messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: ill add some more code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that big hunk of code is in your `viewDidLoad` the problem is simple - you have a local `messages` variable that you setup in `viewDidLoad` and your `numberOfRowsInSection` is referencing an uninitialized `messages` instance variable.

Assuming you really do have an ivar named `messages`, in `viewDidLoad`, change:

```
NSMutableArray *messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

to:

```
messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```